# End of month Q & A Day

Tags: discussion, events

So I've made a new event for the end of the month:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule

Please do register for it if you can and are keen to discuss the site, add questions and help answer the unanswered ones.

Agenda:

- evangelising of the site
- regular chat events
- tag wiki marathon?
- 10 minutes of asking new questions - with people in the chat available to answer
- how to boost the question count?

Comment: perhaps also add any other items to be discussed - eg is [tag:georgia] a country? ;)

Comment: End of April only, or end of each month?